# New array based on objects inside another array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of appointments objects:

```
let appointments = [
    { _id: 54321, name: 'app 1', date: "2022-01-20T09:00:00+01:00"},
    { _id: 66756, name: 'app 2', date: "2022-01-20T08:00:00+01:00"},
    { _id: 76889, name: 'app 3', date: "2022-01-21T08:00:00+01:00"},
    { _id: 35790, name: 'app 4', date: "2022-01-22T08:00:00+01:00"},
    { _id: 35790, name: 'app 5', date: "2022-01-25T09:00:00+01:00"}
]
```

my goal is to create a new array based on the days of the appointments and place them inside, like so:

```
{ days:
    { 2022-01-20: [
     { _id: 54321, name: 'app 1', date: "2022-01-20T09:00:00+01:00"},
     { _id: 66756, name: 'app 2', date: "2022-01-20T08:00:00+01:00"}
    ]},
    { 2022-01-21: [
     { _id: 76889, name: 'app 3', date: "2022-01-21T08:00:00+01:00"}
    ]},
     { 2022-01-22: [
     { _id: 35790, name: 'app 4', date: "2022-01-22T08:00:00+01:00"}
    ]},
     { 2022-01-23: []},
     { 2022-01-24: []},
     { 2022-01-25: [
      { _id: 35790, name: 'app 5', date: "2022-01-25T09:00:00+01:00"}
     ]},
}
```

The first 10 characters of 'date' could become the new values (excluding duplicates) and inside them there should be the proper appointments, as they are in the source - only organized by the days.

Another feature that I'm trying to make is inserting empty days between the active days (example in the second code)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: It's important to understand that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. You should always make a good faith effort to solve your problem and include your code and results when you ask for help.

Comment: I understand both comments, but I did try solving this for over 4 hours and not comfortable sharing my half baked result. please, if you don't feel like solving this just let someone else help here.

Comment: i guess what you need to do is reduce your array to create an abject based on the date, appointments is bad because there is not dates that similar
but you can plain around with reduce itself

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69561827/edit) to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
const appointments = [
    { _id: 54321, name: 'app 1', date: "2022-01-20T09:00:00+01:00"},
    { _id: 66756, name: 'app 2', date: "2022-01-20T08:00:00+01:00"},
    { _id: 76889, name: 'app 3', date: "2022-01-21T08:00:00+01:00"},
    { _id: 35790, name: 'app 4', date: "2022-01-22T08:00:00+01:00"},
    { _id: 35790, name: 'app 5', date: "2022-01-25T09:00:00+01:00"}
];

const appointmentsByDate = appointments.reduce(
  (acc, appointment) => {
    // split the date string and store index 0 as date variable.
    const [date] = appointment.date.split('T');
    return {
      ...acc,
      // overwrite or add date key to the accumulator.
      // if the date key already exists, spread the existing value into the new value
      [date]: [...(acc[date] || []), appointment], 
    };
  },
  {} // starting accumulator (acc) value
);

console.log(appointmentsByDate);
```